# Find a $\delta >0$ so that $|x -2| < \delta$ implies $| x^2 -4x + 4| <1/n$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $\delta = \sqrt{1/n}$. Then for $x$ such that $|x-2|< \delta$ we have $|x-2|< \sqrt{1/n}$, so that $|x^2-4x+4|=|x-2|\cdot|x-2|<\sqrt{1/n}\cdot\sqrt{1/n} = 1/n$.

The breakdown into 2 of the same absolute values is throwing me off. Thoughts?

Comment: Complete solution of question!

Comment: Is there no function associated with this?

Comment: @SirJective it's all I am given.

Comment: What is the question? :)

Answer (score 0):

We have: $$\left|x^2-4x+4\right|=\left|(x-2)^2\right|=\left|(x-2)(x-2)\right|=\left|x-2\right|\cdot\left|x-2\right|.$$

Is this the bit you are stuck on?

Comment: Yes, and since I know that must be < 1/n, that's how I came up with \sqrt(1/n)